# Is there a way in scala for printing the size of a list beetween a function chaining?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Of course, I could break this code by extracting the list after the filter or the map function and print the size. But for the sake of learning i am wondering whether there is a nicer solution where i could keep this function chaining.

`listOfSomething.filter(condition).map(e => e.mapToSomeOther).mkString(DELIMITER)`

Comment: use a variable i.e. counter into the chain i guess not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, afaik, no methods on immutable sequences that have side effects, but you can enrich the API with side-effect methods (I don't recommend this) like so:

```
scala> implicit class PrintSize[T](xs: List[T]){ def printSize = { println(xs.size); xs} }
defined class PrintSize

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).filter(_ > 3).printSize.map(_ * 2).mkString(",")
4
res2: String = 8,10,12,14
```

Your first suggestion about extracting temporary results is much better, because you can do your side effects *after or before the entire computation*.

Comment: Cool! That's what i was looking for. I extended it a bit so i could alter the filter process and inject the printing part:
`implicit class FilterWithLog[T](xs: Set[T]) {
    def filterEntities(filter: T => Boolean ) = {
      val filteredEntities = xs.filter(filter)
      println(s"Number of Entities went down from ${xs.size} to ${filteredEntities.size}")
    }
  }`

However, it looks like overengineering so yes, i'll stay with the original temporary result extraction solution. It just needed for my learning curve.